# Alert buttons are not displayed in React Native

Tags: react-native, android-alertdialog

The following code is supposed to display the 'OK' button, but it is not displayed on Android (at least not on 8.0, 9.0). I am using react-native 0.59.9.

Have you seen anything alike?

```
Alert.alert(
              'Alert Title',
              'My Alert Msg',
              [
                { text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') },
              ],
              { cancelable: true },
            );
```

[image: The Alert without the button]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was (on Android only) that one of the packages I am using defined resource files, and the styles.xml file included the following line:

```
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Changing it to #000000 (black) solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Working Example: https://github.com/WrathChaos/RN-Alert-Example

- npm i
- react-native run-android

Can you try with this?

```
import { Alert } from "react-native";

Alert.alert(
    // ? Title
    "Title",
    // ? Body
    `Boooddyyy`,
    [
      {
        text: "Settings",
        onPress: () => {}
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => {},
        style: "cancel"
      }
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  );
```

Comment: I need to install react-native-open-settings for that?

Comment: Nope, it is just an example from my own code. Let me clear it.

Comment: Now, you can simply copy & paste the code and edit what you need for.

Comment: Thanks. Same behavior

Comment: https://github.com/WrathChaos/RN-Alert-Example

@Yossi, here is the working example. All you need to do is:
npm i
react-native run-ios/android

Comment: Upgrading is a headache. I won't do it only to solve this problem. The code tgat doesn't work now used to work in earlier versions of rn. Thanks a lot for your effort!